# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
export class MustMatchDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('mustMatch') mustMatch: string[] = [];

    validate(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
        return MustMatch(this.mustMatch[0], this.mustMatch[1])(formGroup); <-error here
    }
}
```

```js
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) { 
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => { 
        const control = formGroup.controls[controlName]; 
        const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName]; 
        if (matchingControl.errors 
            && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) { 
            return; 
        } 

        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) { 
            matchingControl.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true }); 
        } else { 
            matchingControl.setErrors(null); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

May I know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please share your `MustMatch` method.

Comment: @YongShun here

export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string){
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
        const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];
        if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) {
            return;
        }
        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
            matchingControl.setErrors({ confirmedValidator: true });
        } else {
            matchingControl.setErrors(null);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @YongShun i dont exactly know how to share properly since I am new to stackoverflow. my bad

Comment: @Haybiz You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow function returned inside `MustMatch` function needs to return something, currently it returns `void` (like the error tells you). It needs to return `ValidationErrors | null`.

```
export class MustMatchDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('mustMatch') mustMatch: string[] = [];

    validate(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
        return MustMatch(this.mustMatch[0], this.mustMatch[1])(formGroup); <-error here
    }
}
```

```
export function MustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) { 
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => { 
        const control = formGroup.controls[controlName]; 
        const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName]; 
        if (matchingControl.errors 
            && !matchingControl.errors.confirmedValidator) { 
            return null; 
        } 

        let error: ValidationErrors | null;
        if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
            error = { confirmedValidator: true };
        } else {
            error = null; 
        }
        matchingControl.setErrors(error);
        return error;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I seee. that solved the problem. thanks! really appreciate it.

Comment: @Haybiz I'm glad I could help :) Would be great if you could express your appreciation by accepting my answer!